# How to use SVG symbols in CSS?

Tags: css, html, svg

[Using symbols in SVG formats](http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) seems like a good idea to me, so you can only load a single SVG file, and use it as a sort of spritemap.

It feels wrong to me though, to directly include the `<svg></svg>` tags in my html for icons, since they are presentation only and should be added in my CSS.

Is there a way to add a symbol from an svg in an `:after` pseudo element in my CSS?

Comment: Sure -- you can store them as an external `*.svg` file, and add them using `.classname:after { content: url(/path/to/file.svg); }`

Comment: Or you could encode them as data URLs within the CSS file itself.

Comment: I want to use symbols, not the whole svg, since I want to use it as "spritemap".

Comment: @enyo Did you find any way to get this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's kind of strange, since I would have assumed that this is a pretty common use case...

Comment: Seems like you had better use `<view>` rather than `<symbol>` see here : https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

Comment: I really enjoy using the SVG with :use - to target parts of a larger SVG, but you have to include the whole SVG for cross-broswer reasons as of now. I love fontastic for this.  https://css-tricks.com/using-svg   images can be  'presentation only' and we put them in our HTML.

Answer (score 7):

You can refer to fragments in CSS this way (fragments must have an ID to identified):

```
.element {
background-image: url('vector.svg#fragment');
}
```

You can also show a specific area by clipping it with viewBox:

```
.element {
background-image: url('vector.svg#fragment(viewBox(0,0,25,25))');
}
```

Here you can read more about this methods:
http://www.broken-links.com/2012/08/14/better-svg-sprites-with-fragment-identifiers/

Another method could be to create all your symbols in a icon font.

Comment: The limiting to the fragment does not seem to currently work in Chrome 62. https://jsfiddle.net/b2n5tude/

Comment: The OP was talking about SYMBOLS. The method shown here is using VIEWS. Different technology.

Comment: It does not seem possible with symbols. This solution is a good alternative if you can adjust the svg file

Answer (score -1):

As Blazemonger mentioned in comment you can give it inside the `content` of an `after`element.

But if you are setting it as a `background` of an `after` you would have more control over it regarding its `size`,`position` and any other properties a background image can have

html

```
<div id = "mydiv"><div>
```

css

```
#mydiv{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background:tomato;
}

#mydiv:after{
    content:"After of #mydiv";
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background:url('http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/tmp/sharp-icons/svg-icon.svg') no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    border:solid 1px tomato;
}
```

You can save the svg as  a separate file and give it as `url` for `background`
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/um1xrjvo/1/)

Read more on ways of adding SVG to page [here](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Comment: Yes, but you have to link the **whole** SVG and not a single symbol or def which might form part of that SVG file which was mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I want to use symbols, not the whole svg, since I want to use it as "spritemap".

Comment: @enyo you can adjust the background position  to use it as a sprite map.

Comment: I know. I want to use symbols.